# Controls in MPMoviePlayerController disabled

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Here is my code :

```
-(void) playVideo
{
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.criteriaFilter.videoUrl];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.displayVideoView.bounds];
    self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.displayVideoView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

}
```

In portrait mode, the controls work fine (play, pause, fullscreen).
However in landscape mode all the buttons seem to be disabled. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: problem is not with code check again that, you are not disabling its button any where else.

Comment: I am not disabling it anywhere else.

Comment: You mean when you are making it landscap mode than all controll are not displaying right?

Comment: Exactly. All controls are disabled. When i rotate my device to portrait mode, the controls are enabled again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem you have described in comment can be solve by adding this code in your code.

```
self.moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Is there any way to increase the height of the movie player in landscape mode. When i added the line of code, it reduced the height of the player. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know much about it but i suggest you to check its apple developer page for MPMoviePlayerController.